# `,omitempty` and pointer fields in Go's standard `xml` package

Tags: xml, go, pointers

When marshalling a boolean field of a struct to XML, the `,omitempty` option is not very useful for most purposes—`false` is a zero value of boolean variables in Go and, as expected, boolean `,omitempty` fields with value of false are ignored when marshalling. The most often suggested solution seems to be using pointers which would allow to indicate whether a value is present at all. Here is my basic implementation of this idea:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"person"`
    IsMarried *bool    `xml:"married"`           // Required field.
    IsRetired *bool    `xml:"retired,omitempty"` // Optional field.
}

func boolPointer(b bool) *bool {
    return &b
}

func printPersonXml(person Person) {
    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(person, "  ", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(output))
    }
}

func main() {
    person := Person{
        IsMarried: boolPointer(true),
        IsRetired: nil,
    }
    printPersonXml(person)
}
```

This works as expected and produces the output

```
  <person>
      <married>true</married>
  </person>
```

However, it seems that in this case `,omitempty` option loses its meaning entirely. *Any* field with `nil` value will not be included in the produced XML code. For example, if I change the contents of `main()` to

```golang
person := Person{
    IsMarried: nil,
    IsRetired: nil,
}
printPersonXml(person)
```

the output becomes

```
  <person></person>
```

even though I would prefer

```
  <person>
      <married></married>
  </person>
```

As noted [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal), this is probably the expected behaviour: "Marshal handles a pointer by marshaling the value it points at or, if the pointer is nil, by writing nothing."

However, is it possible to achieve my preferred behaviour using standard `xml` package? If yes, would that require introducing a new type and a custom `MarshalXML()` method for it?

Although here I focus on boolean variables for obvious reasons, I would like to extend this approach to pointers of other basic types as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"is it possible to achieve my preferred behaviour using standard xml package? If yes, would that require introducing a new type and a custom MarshalXML() method for it?"* -- Yes, and yes.

For example:

```golang
type Bool struct {
    Bool    bool
    IsValid bool
}

func (b Bool) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, se xml.StartElement) error {
    if b.IsValid {
        return e.EncodeElement(b.Bool, se)
    }
    return e.EncodeElement("", se)
}

type OptionalBool struct {
    Bool    bool
    IsValid bool
}

func (b OptionalBool) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, se xml.StartElement) error {
    if b.IsValid {
        return e.EncodeElement(b.Bool, se)
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/C2fuBfv69Ny

Comment: Thank you for this! However, it doesn't exactly produce the behaviour I want. I did try this method before because I'm using `sql` package which uses the `Null<T>` types like the ones in your code. The problem is that I *do* want there to be a tag for the required field, even if `Bool.Valid == false`. I.e. if I set `person.IsMarried` to `Bool{false, false}`, it should produce the code `<married></married>`.

Comment: @user121169 I've updated the answer, does it solve your problem now?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Ideally, I would have wanted to control everything through the inclusion or exclusion of `,omitempty`, but that will work. It seems that whether `,omitempty` (or any other option for that matter) is set is not accessible from within `MarshalXML()`.